# rootViewController conflicting with navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, rootviewcontroller

So I am doing this tutorial on how to create your own slide-out menu:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

The tutorial states that the view controllers can be swapped out for your own. So I incorporated it into my own app with adjustments.

Only problem is, this code below is conflicting with my navigation controller which is the initial view controller. The slide out menu works great but the app loads without any other content. I imagine the rootViewConroller is conflicting the initial view controller but I tried one without the other and a variety of other things with no luck.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()

    window!.rootViewController = containerViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: hard to debug as such. maybe upload your proj on github to look for

Comment: okay try .. `containerViewController = UIStoryboard(name:"main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("containerVC")` this is all from memory so fix type and names yourself please

Comment: I am unable to post the project unfortunately. I attempted your suggestion and while no success, my content is still there which is a plus but the slide out does not work. I see where you are getting at with this though. Attempt to call ViewController with storyboard as opposed to the class itself.

Comment: @DG7 did you ever get a resolution to this? I'm following the same tutorial with the same issue